# how to change drop-down navigation text typeface and color?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

After a lot of search and no answer(or a simple answer),
I have a activity that have a action bar spinner on it(created by android studio simple wizard). there is a code snippet:

```
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(

            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    actionBar.getThemedContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    android.R.id.text1,
                    new String[]{
                            getString(R.string.title_section1),
                            getString(R.string.title_section2),
                            getString(R.string.title_section3),
                    }),
            this);
```

considering that list items is string based how can I change typeface and textcolor?

works I have done: 1-changed Arrayadapter and `new String[]` type to textview. 2-tried to change `android.R.id.text1` to my own `R.id.textview`.
(my app supports api 8+)
please tell a simple way because I am new in android programming.

Comment: Did you read this? [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Comment: Styles is in xml so I can just change textcolor on that. Typeface is more important for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.sortby_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item) { 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent); 
Typeface externalFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/your font name here"); 
((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont); return v; 
} 
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
View v =super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
 Typeface externalFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ your font name here");
 ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont); return v;
 } 
};
```

Comment: I have problem with R.array! any ideas? but still I think this code not works in 'actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks' method